# vertical listing of variable names

Tags: sas

I often want to paste all of the variable names of a dataset into one column in an Excel file.

```
proc contents data=mydata varnum short;
run;
```

will give me the names separated by spaces in ODS. I run text-to-columns and then paste-transpose the results to get the format that I want.

I want that same output, but separated by line breaks instead of spaces so that I can easily paste them into a single column in Excel.

Thanks for your suggestions,
pT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the table view vcolumn in the library SASHELP will give you the what you need.  This table view is automatically generated by sas.

proc sql noprint;

```
   create table vars as
   select name 
   from sashelp.vcolumn
   where libname = upper("work")
      and
         memname = upper("table1")
   ;
quit;
```

where work is your library and table1 is the table you want the variables from

Comment: What's working best for me is to include `order by varnum` and drop the `noprint` and `create table`. That gives me the single column printed and selectable on the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use proc contents, make it output to a dataset:

```
proc contents data=mydata noprint out=mydata_varnames (keep=name);
run;
```

Then either open the dataset and copy-paste, or export the data to a file using proc export. (e.g., a csv file. i'm not a fan of exporting directly to xls)

Comment: unfortunately, the output dataset seems to always be written in alphabetical order, when I want to keep these in date-of-creation order. I can include `keep=name varnum`, then sort it and drop the varnum, but I'm looking for a minimum number of steps.